# tmutil setdestination permission denied

Tags: time-machine, smb

I'm trying to force TimeMachine to point to an smb location. The smb share is on a Ubuntu server and I followed [this guide](https://kirb.me/2018/03/24/using-samba-as-a-time-machine-network-server.html) (mostly - it's a little outdated) to setup the smb.

However, I do not see my smb in TimeMachine, so I'm running:

`sudo tmutil setdestination 'smb://myusername:mypassw0rd@myserver/timemachine'`

and I'm getting back:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied (error 13)
The backup destination could not be set.
```

How do I go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: quoting from `man tmutil`: "Several, but not all, verbs require root and Full Disk Access privileges." So whenever you use `tmutil` you should expect to use `sudo` unless you *know* that you do not need it.

Comment: Just left out sudo here. Had it when I ran it

Answer (score 0):

It was a permissions issue. I realized I couldn't even run `touch somefile` as my user while logged in directly on the remote machine.

Running `sudo chmod -R 777 /media/timemachine` and `sudo chown youruser /media/timemachine` may fix the issue for you.

Worth noting, I formatted /media/timemachine as ext4

Comment: Note that 777 means that everyone can access it, which you may not want. Chown should suffice